# Создать WebView между двумя UILabel swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, webview, autolayout

Мне надо создать WebView программно в `ViewController-e` со **ScrollView** и только когда необходимо. По умолчанию его нет. **Также надо его размесить между двумя Label.** Также меня интересует как закрепить его AutoLayout. Спасибо.

**iOS 9.*, Swift 3**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var webView: WKWebView?

func createWebView() {
    self.webView = WKWebView()
    let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
    self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.scrollView.addSubview(webView)

    self.webView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:self.topLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier:1, constant:0))
    self.webView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:self.bottomLabel, attribute: .top, multiplier:1, constant:0))
    self.webView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.webView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:self.scrollView, attribute: .width, multiplier:1, constant:0))
    self.webView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.webView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem:self.scrollView, attribute: .centerX, multiplier:1, constant:0))
}
```